# SwiftUI ViewGraph fatal error on running app

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a problem time to time running my app. When app crashes the error is:

SwiftUI/ListHeaderFooterCellSupport.swift:72: Fatal error: PlatformListViewBase has no ViewGraph!
2023-01-24 12:41:04.886495+0200 AppHere[10301:2175189] SwiftUI/ListHeaderFooterCellSupport.swift:72: Fatal error: PlatformListViewBase has no ViewGraph!

The crash does not happen all the time, it happens some times. And it is upredictable, I try to do different things to catch where is the problem, but seems that I cant quite get it.

Is it something on adding List to view?

If so, here is a design how I bult my view:

```
          ForEach(handler.categorys, id: \.id){ category in
            Section {
                List{
                    ForEach(category.menuItems!, id: \.id){ item in
                        MenuItemCell(overviewHandler: overviewHandler,
                                     item: item,
                                     currency: currency)
                    }
                }
            } header: {
                Text("Menu item's - \(category.categoryName!)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess. Move the List out of the ForEach. Meaning you have the List on the outside and it contains the ForEach with the Section and the second ForEach.
Each List is a ScrollView and creating ScrollViews inside what you already have might cause conflicts. (Generally, ScrollViews in other ScrollViews are difficult)